# Problema en la consulta con INNER JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server

El problema es en la parte del inner join realiza un loop infinito y en el plan de ejecución me tira error.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   cli.NRO_ID_NORMALIZADO AS NRO_IDENTIFICACION,
   cli.TIPO_ID AS TIPO_IDENTIFICACION,
   'N' AS PRINCIPAL,
   try_convert(varchar(2), dbo.fnOptenerValorHomologado('DAV_CLASE_CEL_MAIL', 'cl_ttelefono', try_convert(varchar(2), te_tipo_telefono), '9') ) AS CLASE_CELULAR,
   TRY_CONVERT( VARCHAR(18) , tel.te_valor ) AS NRO_CELULAR,
   'Y' AS ACTIVO,
   '506' AS PAIS,
   TRY_CONVERT(DECIMAL(2, 0) , 0 ) AS INDICATIVO 
FROM
   cl_ente e 
   INNER JOIN
      CLIENTES cli 
      on (cli.ORIGEN = 'INTNEG' 
      and cli.NATURALEZA_JURIDICA = 'EMPRESA' 
      and cli.EN_ENTE IS NULL 
      and cli.NRO_ID_NORMALIZADO IS NOT NULL) 
   JOIN
      cl_telefono tel 
      ON( en_subtipo = 'C' 
      AND te_ente = e.en_ente 
      AND te_tipo_telefono = '5')
```

Esta es la imagen del plan de ejecución

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No estás definiendo ningún criterio para relacionar campos de `cl_ente` y de `CLIENTES` en el inner join. Eso que pones realmente iría en el WHERE pero bueh...

Comment: aunque lo ponga en un where me tira el mismo problema

Comment: porque **sigues sin poner condiciones que vinculen las dos tablas**. INNER JOIN es decirle a la BD **Une estas dos tablas por esta columna de A y estas columnas de B**, no hay magia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No es que se esté creando un loop infinito. Lo que se está creando es un producto cartesiano en el que todas las filas de una tabla se relacionan con todas las filas de la otra tabla. Las condiciones del JOIN solo hacen referencia a columnas de la tabla `CLIENTES` y no hacen referencia a la tabla `cl_ente`.

A continuación, dejo un ejemplo abstracto de lo que está pasando. En la que 2 tablas usando un supuesto `INNER JOIN` transforman 10 filas de cada una en 100 filas (10x10). Si esto se traduce a tablas con un millón de filas cada una, estaríamos hablando de que se regresan un billón (un millón de millones) de filas. Por eso es importante definir las condiciones para unir las tablas.

```
CREATE TABLE Tabla1( ID int)
INSERT INTO Tabla1 VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10)

CREATE TABLE Tabla2( ID int)
INSERT INTO Tabla2 VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10)

SELECT *
FROM Tabla1 t1
INNER JOIN Tabla2 t2 ON t1.ID >= 1

GO
DROP TABLE Tabla1, Tabla2
```

Al no conocer la estructura de tus tablas, no puedo hacer una sugerencia específica para solucionar tu problema. Sin embargo, tomando el ejemplo anterior, podría solucionarlo estableciendo una relación entre ambas tablas que generan un resultado de 10 filas.

```
SELECT *
FROM Tabla1 t1
INNER JOIN Tabla2 t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

En el INNER JOIN no estás diciendo la tabla ***cl_ente*** e y ***CLIENTES cli*** como se relacionan.